# Supremum of product of matrices with norm less than one

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces, supremum-and-infimum

We consider 2 invertible matrices $A_{1}$ and $A_{2}$, and a submultiplicative norm $\|.\|$ such that $\|A_{1}\|\le 1$ and $\|A_{2}\|\le 1$. My goal is to find:
$$
\sup\limits_{i_{1}\in \mathbb N^{*},i_{2}\in \mathbb N^{*},i_{3}\in \mathbb N}\|A_{1}^{i_1}A_{2}^{i_2}A_{1}^{i_3}\|
$$

My intuition says that the supremum is achieved when $i_{1}=1, i_{2}=1,i_{3}=0$. I tried to prove this by induction but no luck. Does any one can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the submultiplicativity of the norm, if $p,q,r$ are three integers such that $p,q\ge1$ and $r\ge0$, then
\begin{aligned}
\|A_1^pA_2^qA_1^r\|
&\le\|A_1^pA_2^q\|\|A_1\|^r\\
&\le\|A_1^pA_2^q\|\\
&\le\|A_1^pA_2\|\|A_2\|^{q-1}\\
&\le\|A_1^pA_2\|\\
&\le\|A_1\|^{p-1}\|A_1A_2\|\\
&\le\|A_1A_2\|.
\end{aligned}

Comment: Thank you, and if i want to generalize, can i assume that for $p,q,r,s\ge1$ and $t\ge 0$:$$\|A_{1}^{p}A_{2}^{q}A_{1}^{r}A_{2}^{s}A_{1}^{t}\|\le\|(A_{1}A_{2})^{2}\|?$$

Comment: @pioneer Apparently not. You can remove all leading terms and trailing terms, but that doesn't give you $A_1A_2A_1A_2$.

Comment: Thank you, actually my final goal is to have some information about the generalized inequality, i will ask a new question for that.